# Is this function a continuous function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If I define a function over the non rational numbers:

$ f: \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

$f(x) = 1$

is it continuous ? I think it is because all the points on the domain in any interval have $f(x)-1 = 0$

Comment: Yep. Even if you define $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x) = 1$, it is still continuous.

Comment: even if it has some small intervals without any point of the domain ? Can a function defined on only two points be continuous ?

Comment: @Soke, that's only in nonstandard topologies on Z though, isn't it?

Comment: @Tyler here is my reasoning: $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ if there exists $\delta$ such that  $|x - c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. If $f$ is defined over the integers, then $\delta = 1/2$ makes the statement vacuously true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this function is continuous.  Let's prove it rigorously.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Let $x \in \Bbb R - \Bbb Q$.  We want to find some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

You can actually pick any $\delta > 0$.  This is because if $\delta > 0$, $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| = |1 - 1| = 0 < \epsilon$.  Regardless of which $\delta$ you choose, since $f(x) = f(y)$, we will always have $|f(x) - f(y)| = 0 < \epsilon$.